# Caused by: org.ehcache.core.spi.ServiceLocator$DependencyException: Multiple factories for non-plural service

Tags: ehcache, ehcache-3

We are getting below error while initializing ehcache:

```
Caused by: org.ehcache.core.spi.ServiceLocator$DependencyException: Multiple factories for non-plural service
    at org.ehcache.core.spi.ServiceLocator$DependencySet.lookupService(ServiceLocator.java:382)
    at org.ehcache.core.spi.ServiceLocator$DependencySet.lookupDependenciesOf(ServiceLocator.java:357)
    at org.ehcache.core.spi.ServiceLocator$DependencySet.build(ServiceLocator.java:316)
```

Source Code to initialize cache:

> CacheManager cacheManager =
> Caching.getCachingProvider("org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider")
> .getCacheManager(); Cache<K, V> cache = cacheManager.getCache("my-cache");

ehcache version: 3.8.1

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception running my app from Eclipse.
Cause was that I had 2 different versions of ehcache.jar in my classpath (3.6.1 & 3.10.8)